# Testing Write Functions with Mocha/Chai

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mocha.js, chai

We are in the process of writing unit tests for our Node/MongoDB API using Mocha with Chai. My question involves what's recommended when testing write functions. Specifically, how does one handle testing the results of, for instance, an `update()` function, without actually updating the record in the database?

Does mocha have some way of handling this specifically? Is the recommendation to use a test db? Or to roll back changes after they're made? Or some other option?

Here's an example of one of our test functions:

```
  describe("remove()", function() {
    let testTeammember, results;
    before(async function() {
      // Look for a teammember using standard MongoDB syntax
      testTeammember = await db.collection("teammembers").findOne();
      if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(testTeammember._id)) fail("Failed because id is not a valid Mongo ObjectId");

      // Confirm that a teammember is available for testing
      if (!testTeammember) throw "Failed to load test teammember";

      const teamId = testTeammember._id.toString();

      const params = { id: teamId };
      const auth = await TestHelper.generateTestAuth("asmith", apikey);
      results = await TeamCtlr.remove(params, auth);
    });

    it("should be truthy if passed valid params and auth", function() {
      assert.isOk(results);
    });

    it("should return a number for the 'count' property", function() {
      assert.typeOf(results.count, "number");
    });

    it("should have a 'count' of 1", function() {
      expect(results.count).to.equal(1);
    });

    it("results should have a property 'data'", function() {
      expect(results).to.have.property("data");
    });

    it("should return an object for the 'data' property", function() {
      assert.isObject(results.data);
    });

    it("should have a property 'deleted' of type 'boolean'", function() {
      assert.isBoolean(results.data.deleted);
    });

    it("should have 'deleted' set to 'true'", function() {
      expect(results.data.deleted).to.equal(true);
    });

    it("should return a JSON object", function() {
      expect(results).to.exist;
    });
  });
```

So, for the above code, I want to test that the `remove()` function works as expected. But I don't want to end up actually saving these changes to that record in the database.

Comment: I would use a test db and add dummy data to it for since it will actually read/write to the db.  What I've done specifically is insert whatever I need into the db before each test case and then perform the test.

Comment: you don't want and must not (it's not your role) test the db functionalities. So you need to mock the db functionalities (not use a db). The most popular library to mock with mocha is [sinon.js](https://sinonjs.org/)

Comment: You can refer to [this tutorial](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/best-practices-for-spies-stubs-and-mocks-in-sinon-js)